# Python requests 0.x code port to 2.x

Tags: python, python-requests

I had a really simple piece of code working with Python requests 0.x but when I updated to 2.x it no longer works.

The code would return me the color contained within `'field1'`:

```
import time
import requests


# Read the thingspeak feed to get the current colour
while True:
    cheerlights = requests.get('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1417/field/1/last.json').json['field1']
    print(cheerlights)
time.sleep(16)
```

When I run this not I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cheelightsJsonHELP.py", line 7, in 
    cheerlights = requests.get('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1417/field/1/last.json').json['field1']
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I have read the documentation on migrating from 0.x to 2.x but unfortunately this is not a strong area of mine, can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`response.json()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) is now a *method*, where in the past it was a property; add `()` to call it:

```
response = requests.get('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1417/field/1/last.json')
cheerlights = response.json()['field1']
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1417/field/1/last.json')
>>> response.json()['field1']
'orange'
```